# Execute script after load input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload

I have an input file field to select files to upload, and I use ajax to send these pics to server. For execute all script after a file is selected, I use submit, but I think it could be better not to include the submit button and use jquery to detect when I select the file and process the submit action then.

My code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#form_up').ajaxForm({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: bol
    });
});

function bol(datab) {
    if (datab.field_empty == "bad") {
        jQuery(".bol_request_fail").fadeIn(3000);
    } else {}
}
</script>


<form name="form" method="post" id="form_up" runat="server" action="indexer_upload_user_pic.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:0px;">

<input type="file" name="upload[imagen][]" id="logo2" class="file-upload"/>

</form>
```

I use one plugin for send the fields and all form by this you can see ajaxForm function.

The question is: How I can avoid using submit and instead send the pic when it is selected via file input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt test it, but this might work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#logo2").change(function(){
        jQuery('#form_up').ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: 'json',
            success: bol
        });
     });
});
```

Check the Plugin API if this dont work, I just quick checked it, and saw there is a `ajaxSubmit`...